# When I click on a google map marker can I use ajax to update a Div?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map that I have created and its building markers from a database. I am filling those markers with information from the DB. What I would like to do is fill in that information on a div to the right of the map. My thinking is that if I can send the ID of the marker via ajax to a page that will look up the information and reload that page with the information.  I am at best an ajax neophyte and I'm not sure where to begin.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not difficult when you use jQuery, I would suggest to use the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)-method. It starts a ajax-request and loads the response into the target:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          $('#divID').load('some.php?id=123');
        });
```

(where divID is the ID of the element where you wnat the response to appear)

Comment: you can also define custom properties of the marker that can be accessed. `$('#divID').load('some.php?id='+marker.markerid)`

Comment: also make sure you open the infowindow as well to get the desired behavior

Comment: Which infowindow? The question is not about infoWindows.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am going to try this method and report back. It is most appreciated.

Comment: I think this will do it for me. I just ran a quick test and it loaded a quick hello world page. I Will work on passing the value over so that I can fill it with real information now. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok Seem to have hit a snag: Here is some code: 

function setMarkers(map, markers) {

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
 var sites = markers[i];
 var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: siteLatLng,
  map: map,
  title: sites[0],
  zIndex: sites[3],
  html: sites[4]
 });

 var contentString = "Some content";

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
   $('#msf_map_details').load('http://127.0.0.1:8500/j.cfm?');
  });
 }
}

Comment: Ok Seem to have hit a snag: Here is some code: 
`
function setMarkers(map, markers) {

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
 var sites = markers[i];
 var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: siteLatLng,
  map: map,
  title: sites[0],
  zIndex: sites[3],
  html: sites[4]
 });`

I would like to pass the variable (that I generated) called zIndex this will allow me to look up info in the DB. 
`$('#msf_map_details').load('http://127.0.0.1:8500/j.cfm?'& zIndex);` gives me an error.

Comment: should be something like `$('#msf_map_details').load('http://127.0.0.1:8500/j.cfm?zindex='+ zIndex)`

Comment: Thanks! this did it. + instead of &. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

When you create marker you insert html into the infoWindow see line `var html`

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, id) {
var html = "<b> Marker " + id + "</b> <br/><br/><button onclick='doIt("+id+")'>Do It</button>";var image = "icons/XX.png";
  var shadow = "icons/XXX.png";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    icon: image,
    shadow: shadow
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
```

}

The `function doIt(id)`   will do Ajax to reload.

Comment: this adds too much complexity - the user needs to click on the marker then click on the button in the infowindow as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works by clicking on polygons rather than markers (but the concept is the same):

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_world_countries_simple.html

**code snippet (with markers):**

```js
var map = null;

function createMarker(latLng, html) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = html;
  });
}

function openIW(layerEvt) {
  if (layerEvt.row) {
    var content = layerEvt.row['admin'].value;
  } else if (layerEvt.featureData) {
    var content = layerEvt.featureData.name;
  }
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "you clicked on:<br>" + content;
}

function initialize() {
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(36.4278, -15.9);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 0,
    center: chicago,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  createMarker({
    lat: 42,
    lng: -72
  }, "United States");
  createMarker({
    lat: 42,
    lng: 72
  }, "Russia");
  createMarker({
    lat: 37.9838096,
    lng: 23.7275388
  }, "Athens, Greece");
  createMarker({
    lat: -8.783195,
    lng: -55.491477
  }, "South America");

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="map_canvas" style="height:200px; width:300px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="info"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```